# React Native Expo with Firebase: DataSnapshot is object not array

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I have some simple data that looks like this, stored in a realtime database of firestore by calling update() and adding in an array as paremeter.

[image]

The game is generated by creating an array here and setting it in the "participants" field:

```
 generateNewGame(code, name) {
    this.database.ref().update({
      [code]: { participants: [name] },
    });
  }
```

Now it is time to read the data, this is done by this method setting up a listener:

```
function setupRegisteredUsersListener() {
    FirebaseService.getDatabaseReference(
      "/" + codeRef.current + "/participants"
    ).on("value", (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.val()) {
        // setUsers(snapshot.val());
        console.log(typeof snapshot.val());
        console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val(), null, 4));
      }
    });
  }
```

Even though I stored the data as an array, and it LOOKS like an array, the type is Object. How can I circumvent this behaviour, or do I have to manually convert the object to an array somehow?
The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val), says the .val() function should be able to convert the DataSnapshot into an array. But apparently that is not the default in my case.

The output from the function looks like this:

[image]

So obviously the daya is ALMOST an array, but not quite.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to manually convert the object to an array somehow?

No, you can directly use the value returned by `snapshot.val()` as an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

`Array.isArray(snapshot.val())` will return `true`.

Also, for example, the following will return `0`

```
console.log(snapshot.val().findIndex((element) => element === 'Hej'));
```

Or, if you add another element, the following will print the values of the two elements

```
console.log(snapshot.val()[0]);
console.log(snapshot.val()[1]);
```

Comment: Well, the actual problem was mapping the values to the UI form state, which was not seemingly possible, but since I only used the values, I just used Object.values(snapshot.val()) in the state instead, what do you think about that?

Comment: That's totally fine: it returns the array as well.